# Running two user stories in the same Scenario in Cucumber Gherkin

Tags: cucumber, e2e-testing, testcafe, gherkin, cucumberjs

I'm trying to create a scenario where two users would access the application, so I could simulate a sold-out product when one user has it on the cart (more or less).

E.g.

`Given user1 access website`
`Then user1 add a product to the cart`

*Here comes the user2 (not quite sure if I should use another Given or an And, the point here would be opening another window, and keep the window from user1 on hold).*

`Given user2 access website`
`Then user2 add a product to the cart`
`And user2 complete purchase` (Closing the window of user2)

*Here the user1 would try to finish the purchase (back to user1 window)*

`Then user1 tries to finalize the purchase and gets a warning that product is no longer available`

That is more of an idea than the actual flow, but the main point here is to have this "conflict" of empty inventory. I want the user1 to be able to add the product to the cart to later display a warning that the product is no longer available. So, I can't have the Scenario starting with an empty inventory because then the user1 won't even see the product to test against it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use following linear approach.
I assume that it is possible to log 2 users at one browser in different tab's

```
Given user1 access website
When user1 add a product to the cart
And I open 2nd chrome tab
And user2 access website on 2nd tab
And user2 add a product to the cart
And user2 complete purchase
And I close 2nd chrome tab
And I refresh session on 1st tab
Then user1 can not complete purchase and and see 'product no longer available' warn
```

Comment: If my answer is fine please accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use reader-friendly definitions and emphasize the action that lead to your expected result with **When** clause

```
Given One item of "ShortProduct" is available 
   And the following users are registered
    | User Name      |
    | James Luckless |
    | John  Lucky    |
   And "James Luckless" added a "ShortProduct" to the cart
   And "John  Lucky" added a "ShortProduct" to the cart
   And "John  Lucky" completed the purchase
When "James Luckless" attempts to finalize the purchase 
Then "James Luckless" gets a warning that "ShortProduct" is no longer available
```